# How to fix the problem with selecting all values in a multiselect in angular material?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using Angular Material library multiselect. I added an element to this selection, when clicking on which all the elements of the list will be selected, but the problem is that in this case all these elements, together with All, fall into the select field and it looks like this "Value 1, Value 2, Value 3 , Value 4, All ". How can I make it so that in this field when selecting all elements, only the value "All" remains without the rest of the selected elements?

```js
export class AppComponent { 
  searchUserForm: FormGroup;

  userTypeFilters = [
    {
      key: 1, value: 'Value 1',
    },
    {
      key: 2, value: 'Value 2',
    },
    {
      key: 3, value: 'Value 3',
    },
    {
      key: 4, value: 'Value 4',
    }
  ];
  @ViewChild('allSelected') private allSelected: MatOption;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchUserForm = this.fb.group({
      userType: new FormControl('')
    });
  }

  toggleAllSelection() {
    if (this.allSelected.selected) {
      this.searchUserForm.controls.userType
        .patchValue([...this.userTypeFilters.map(item => item.key), 0]);
    } else {
      this.searchUserForm.controls.userType.patchValue([]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="searchUserForm" fxFlex fxLayout="column" autocomplete="off" style="margin: 30px">
    <mat-select placeholder="User Type" formControlName="userType" multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let filters of userTypeFilters" [value]="filters.key">
            {{filters.value}}
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option #allSelected (click)="toggleAllSelection()" [value]="0">All</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</form>
```

Demo is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-znfehg?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the solution**

```html
<form [formGroup]="searchUserForm" fxFlex fxLayout="column" autocomplete="off" style="margin: 30px">
    <mat-select placeholder="User Type" formControlName="userType" multiple>
      <mat-select-trigger *ngIf="allSelected.selected">
       <span>
         ALL
       </span>
      </mat-select-trigger>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let filters of userTypeFilters" [value]="filters.key">
            {{filters.value}}
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option #allSelected (click)="toggleAllSelection()" [value]="0">All</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</form>
```